# Show biometric authentication dialog on activity page instead of showing it as alert dialog

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am implementing biometric prompt for my application. Currently it's authentication dialog is shown as alert dialog .Instead of this I want dialog to be displayed in activity page (I don't want it to be displayed as alert dialog)
I want it like what's app biometric authentication dialog
[Whats app authentication screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2s1MB.png)

Comment: That's the thing about BiometricPrompt; you don't control what it should look like. It's supposed to have the same look across all apps. If WhatsApp has a custom look, then they're probably still using the older FingerprintManager API.